# How to determine the order occurrence of the currently selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to know which occurrence of the currently selected text is selected, in my content div (.entry-content).

My current fiddle built from a previous answer is doing it right... sometimes!

http://jsfiddle.net/FTWLJ/10/

If you select the word **Maecenas** (first word), it gives the correct occurrence when you pick the first one. Try with the first one of the second paragraph and it gives the wrong occurrence. It should be 3.

It seems to work sometimes but not reliably, it perhaps is the use of *elementFromPoint( x, y )*.

**It seems that when you select full words, it doesn't work. When you select half a word and half another word, it works.**

```
$('.entry-content').on('click',function(e){

    //get the x and y coords
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        x = e.clientX - offset.left,
        y = e.clientY - offset.top,
        text;

    //get the highlighted text
    if(window.getSelection){
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != 'Control'){
        //for IE prior to 9
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    //check if the text is empty or just spaces   
    if($.trim(text).length){

        //wrap each word similar to the highlighted text with <span>
        var regex = new RegExp(text,'g')
        $('.entry-content').html($('.entry-content').html().replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">'+text+'</span>'));

        //get the new span index situating on coords
        var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y),
            occurrence = $(el).index()+1,
            exist = $('span').length;       

        alert(exist+' exist | occurrence: '+occurrence);

        //remove the <span> wrapper            
        $('span').contents().unwrap();

    }
});
```

Has anybody a reliable solution for this?

Comment: `document.elementFromPoint()` is not very reliable for your use case. It works if selection is done by double clicking a word, for instance, but if you drag-select, the cursor may be outside the selection (middle of the next letter, for instance) and you will detect the wrong element (in this case, the wrapping `p`). Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/FTWLJ/13/  (matched element will turn red)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the element's index in relation to its parent:

```
occurrence = $(el).index()+1
```

What you want instead is its index in relation to *all* of the spans:

```
occurrence = $('span').index(el)+1
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hbbyhv3k/)

Comment: It works great however, if there body/document had some padding, margin or else, it doesn't work because the element resulting from x and y is not where the actual click was.

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbbyhv3k/2/

Comment: I see the issue.  Change `var offset = $(this).offset()` to `var offset = $(this).position()`.  That will account for the padding, etc.  See http://jsfiddle.net/hbbyhv3k/3/

Comment: perfect, works wonders! spent 48hrs sorting this whole function out, happy it now works!